# Реализовать метод `void sort(IntList list)` который сортирует список IntLinkedList и IntArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, списки, двусвязный-список, linked-list

Всем добрый вечер. Есть реализованные списки `IntLinkedList` и `IntArrayList`, нужно написать метод который сортирует список: `void sort(IntList list)` и продемонстрировать его работу, передав туда сначала `IntArrayList`, потом `IntLinkedList`.

Помогите кто чем может, заранее благодарен.

---

**IntArrayList.java**

```
package com.inguarus;

public class IntArrayList extends BaseList implements IntList {

    private int[] arr = new int[10];


    @Override
    public void add(int element) {
        if (size >= arr.length) {
            resize();
        }
        arr[size] = element;
        size++;
    }

    private void resize() {
        int newSize = arr.length * 3 / 2 + 1;
        int[] newArr = new int[newSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            newArr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        arr = newArr;
    }

    @Override
    public int get(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return arr[index];
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, int element) {
        if (index < 0 || index > size - 1) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        if (size >= arr.length) {
            resize();
        }
        System.arraycopy(arr, index, arr, index + 1, size - index);
        arr[index] = element;
        size++;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        size = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(int value) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == value) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index > size - 1) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        System.arraycopy(arr, index + 1, arr, index, size - index - 1);
        size--;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeElement(int element) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == element) {
                System.arraycopy(arr, i + 1, arr, i, size - i - 1);
                size--;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int index, int element) {
        if (index < 0 || index > size - 1) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        arr[index] = element;
    }
}
```

**IntLinkedList.java**

```
package com.inguarus;

public class IntLinkedList extends BaseList implements IntList {

    private Node first;
    private Node last;

    private static class Node {
        int element;
        Node next;
        Node previous;

        public Node(int element) {
            this.element = element;
        }

        public Node() {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int element) {
        Node newNode = new Node(element);
        if (first == null) {
            newNode.next = null;
            newNode.previous = null;
            first = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        } else {
            last.next = newNode;
            newNode.previous = last;
            last = newNode;
        }
        size++;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, int element) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        Node newNode = new Node(element);
        if (index == 0) {
            newNode.next = first;
            first.previous = newNode;
            first = newNode;
            size++;
            return;
        } else if (index == size - 1) {
            newNode.previous = last;
            last.next = newNode;
            last = newNode;
            size++;
            return;
        }
        Node oldNode = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            oldNode = oldNode.next;
        }
        Node oldPrevious = oldNode.previous;
        oldPrevious.next = newNode;
        oldNode.previous = newNode;
        newNode.previous = oldPrevious;
        newNode.next = oldNode;
        size++;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        first = null;
        last = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(int element) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (get(i) == element) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int get(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        Node result = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            result = result.next;
        }
        return result.element;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index > size - 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if (index == 0) {
            first = first.next;
        } else {
            Node node = findNodeBeforeByIndex(index);
            Node tmp = findByIndex(index);
            node.next = tmp.next;
        }
        size--;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeElement(int element) {

        if (size == 0) {
            return false;
        } else if (size == 1) {
            first = null;
            last = null;
            size = 0;
            return true;
        }

        Node nodeBefore = findNodeBefore(element);

        if (nodeBefore.element == 0) {
            first = first.next;
            size--;
            return true;
        } else if (nodeBefore != null) {
            if (last.element == element) {
                nodeBefore.next = null;
                last = nodeBefore;
            } else {
                nodeBefore.next = nodeBefore.next.next;
            }
            size--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int index, int element) {
        findByIndex(index).element = element;
    }

    private Node findByIndex(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index > size - 1) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        int tmpIndex = 0;
        if (first == null) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

        if (index == 0) {
            return first;
        }

        Node node = first;
        while (node.next != null) {
            node = node.next;
            tmpIndex++;
            if (tmpIndex == index) {
                return node;
            }
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    private Node findNodeBefore(int value) {
        if (first.element == value) {
            return new Node();
        }

        Node node = first;
        while (node.next != null) {
            if (node.next.element == value) {
                return node;
            }
            node = node.next;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Node findNodeBeforeByIndex(int index) {
        if (index <= 0 || index > size - 1) {
            return null;
        }

        int count = 0;
        Node node = first;
        while (node.next != null) {
            if (count == index - 1) {
                return node;
            }
            count++;
            node = node.next;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
package com.inguarus;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IntList arrayList = new IntArrayList();
        arrayList.add(7);
        arrayList.add(3);
        arrayList.add(5);
        arrayList.add(9);
        arrayList.add(11);
        arrayList.add(75);
        arrayList.add(16);
        arrayList.add(38);
        arrayList.add(92);
        arrayList.add(145);
        System.out.println("ArrayList: " + arrayList);

        IntList linkedList = new IntLinkedList();
        linkedList.add(4);
        linkedList.add(87);
        linkedList.add(3);
        linkedList.add(9);
        linkedList.add(12);
        linkedList.add(62);
        linkedList.add(31);
        linkedList.add(2);
        linkedList.add(89);
        linkedList.add(17);

        System.out.println("LinkedList: " + linkedList);
    }
}
```

Comment: list.sort(..) or Comparator.comparingInt(..)

Comment: Collections.sort подойдёт?

Comment: Проблема то в чем? За Вас надо написать? Откройте Collections.sort и перепишите. Или просто оберните его в свой метод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал сортировку с помощью 2-х дополнительных методов:

```
rivate static void sort(IntList list) {
    int[] array = list.makeArrayFromIntList(list);
    int temp, j;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
            temp = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = array[i];
            j = i;
            while (j > 0 && temp < array[j - 1]) {
                array[j] = array[j - 1];
                j--;
            }
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list.makeIntListFromArray(array));
}

public int[] makeArrayFromIntList(IntList list) {
    int[] resultArray = new int[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
        resultArray[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    return resultArray;
}


public IntList makeIntListFromArray(int[] array) {
    IntList resultIntList = new IntArrayList();
    for (int anArray : array) {
        resultIntList.add(anArray);
    }
    return resultIntList;
}
```